# PHP: how to condition max(array_filter) & min(array_filter) if empty

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have created an array using compact:

`$rank_month = compact('jan','feb','mar');`

Like this and the data will be fetch using queries and due to that the data will sometimes will be **empty** and the data will be numbers. 
And then I'm using the `max(array_filter) and min(array_filter)` to get the highest and lowest in the array but when the query is empty I get the

> ERROR: max(): Array must contain at least one element
>
> ERROR: Min(): Array must contain at least one element

is it possible to condition it like:

```
     if(empty(max(array_filter('$rank_month')))){
        $high = ""; }
    else{
    $high = max(array_filter('$rank_month'
}
```

or is their any way to fix this error? Even if the data is empty

Thanks.

Comment: simply what the error says: $rank_month is an empty array

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `array_filter` a ***string*** when it actually wants an *array*.  `'$rank_month'` is an 11-character string, it's not an array.

You want to make sure you pass the *array* to `array_filter` (as well as `min` and `max`).

You also want to be checking the length of the *filtered* array before calling `min`/`max`.

```
$filtered_month = array_filter($rank_month);
if(!empty($filtered_month)){
    $high = max($filtered_month);
}
else{
    $high = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply what the error says: $rank_month is an empty array
use [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) or [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
if (sizeof($rank_month) > 1) {
    $high = max($rank_month);
} else {
   ...
}
```

Or

```
if (count($rank_month) > 1) {
     $high = max($rank_month);
 else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: why do you quota the argument in `max`? also, your comparison in the if condition is wrong.

Comment: remove the quotes from the `max`m it's `max($var);` not `max('$var')`

Comment: @Twisted1919 sorry was busy answering other quesiton... got you.. updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `Array` is empty, not if the `max` value is empty. 
You also don't need to pass in `array_filter`, the array itself should work.

```
if(empty($rank_month)){
    $high = ""; 
} else {
    $high = max($rank_month);
}
```

Comment: i already tried that but it generate`Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write contex`

Comment: Try my updated code, fixed the string instead of array as Rocket Hazmat found.